# Validation phone number with country code using intlTelInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am trying to validate phone numbers with intl-tel-input as shown https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/is-valid-number.html

Here is my code

```
var telInput = $("#phone"), errorMsg = $("#error-msg"), validMsg = $("#valid-msg");

// initialise plugin
telInput.intlTelInput({
nationalMode: true,
utilsScript: "../../build/js/utils.js"
});

var reset = function() {
    telInput.removeClass("error");
    errorMsg.addClass("hide");
    validMsg.addClass("hide");
};

// on blur: validate
telInput.blur(function() {
    reset();
    if ($.trim(telInput.val())) 
    {
        if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) 
        {
          validMsg.removeClass("hide");
        } else {
          telInput.addClass("error");
          errorMsg.removeClass("hide");
        }
    }
});

// on keyup / change flag: reset
telInput.on("keyup change", reset);
```

But i got stuck on how to validate the phone number when i use the international format like ( +255 123 123 123 ).

I hope the problem is clear enough.
Help please

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  Show the code in 'utilsScript'.

Comment: utilsScript is minified

Comment: You can use my prettyrizer: http://bak-o-soft.dk/Prettyrizer/Prettyrizer.aspx. It would be easier to answer your question with some javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching the video link where you will learn how to add an international phone number will all validations

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnx2h_Qura8